# Is it possible to add keydown event on anything other than an input

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onkeydown

```
<div type="text" id="demo">
Hi
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("keypress", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to change the color of the div demo when a key is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by add attribute **tabindex="1"** to the div

**update : ** here is a js fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/dsm97po9/

```
<div tabindex="1" id="demo">
```

try it and tell me